# Is it possible to add more syntax colors to VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Take a look at this picture from my Typescript file:

[image]

It's barely readable. Only 2 colors in that entire block of code? I've tried changing themes but themes only change the colors already used, it doesn't add new colors for variables, methods etc.

Is it possible to add more colors for code syntax in VS code?

Comment: this works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725564/how-can-i-coloring-php-syntax-in-vscode

Comment: I'm writing Typescript code and not get nearly as much colors as your example.