# how can I coloring php syntax in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

in atom php code is great but in vscode is too simple. only 2 or 3 color!

how can I add more color? (customize it or by a plugin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of extensions to change the syntax highlighting, if you like the Atom style you can try this:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. I googled hours for that....